# Не работает скрипт JQuery на поиск и подсветку фрагментов текста на страницу

Tags: jquery

Прошу вам помочь с установкой скрипта *JQuery*, - это первый подобный скрипт который я устанавливаю на свой сайт, и наверняка я что-то упустил.

Скрипт на поиск и подсветку фрагментов текста на страницу. Взят [отсюда](http://damonlsd.ru/jquery-poisk-i-podsvetka-teksta/), и на демо автора работает.

При проверке на сайте *cssdeck.com*, а на *plnkr.co* не работает, так же как и у меня.

[Адрес моей страницы, где я пытаюсь установить код](https://hauk-electro.ru).

Код, который я устанавливаю:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>jQuery: поиск и подсветка текста</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://damonlsd.ru/demo/jquery-poisk/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://damonlsd.ru/demo/jquery-poisk/js/jquery.highlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://damonlsd.ru/demo/jquery-poisk/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>

<style>
.highlight {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,153);
}
.selectHighlight {
    background-color: yellow; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* FF1+ */ 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */ 
    border-radius: 5px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */ 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* FF3.5+ */ 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */ 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Opera 10.5+, IE 9.0 */ 
    padding:1px 4px; 
    margin:0 -4px;
    color:#ff0000;
}
.finded{
    color:white;background: #8A8A7B;
}

input[type="button"] {border-radius: 10px 0 0 0; border: 3px solid red}
input[type="button"]:hover {border-radius: 10px 0 0 0; border: 3px solid blue}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var search_number = 0;
    var search_count = 0;
    var count_text = 0;
    var srch_numb = 0;

    function scroll_to_word(){
        var pos = $('#text .selectHighlight').position();
        jQuery.scrollTo(".selectHighlight", 500, {offset:-150});
    }

    $('#search_text').bind('keyup oncnange', function() {
        $('#text').removeHighlight();
        txt = $('#search_text').val();
        if (txt == '') return;
        $('#text').highlight(txt);
        search_count = $('#text span.highlight').size() - 1;
        count_text = search_count + 1;
        search_number = 0;
        $('#text').selectHighlight(search_number);
        if ( search_count >= 0 ) scroll_to_word();
        $('#count').html('Найдено: <b>'+count_text+'</b>');
    });

    $('#clear_button').click(function() {
        $('#text').removeHighlight();
        $('#search_text').val('поиск');
        $('#count').html('');
        jQuery.scrollTo(0, 500, {queue:true});
    });

    $('#prev_search').click(function() {
        if (search_number == 0) return;
        $('#text .selectHighlight').removeClass('selectHighlight');
        search_number--;
        srch_numb = search_number + 1;
        $('#text').selectHighlight(search_number);
        if ( search_count >= 0 ) { 
            scroll_to_word();
            $('#count').html('Показано: <b>'+srch_numb+'</b> из '+$('#text span.highlight').size());
        }
    });

    $('#next_search').click(function() {
        if (search_number == search_count) return;
        $('#text .selectHighlight').removeClass('selectHighlight');
        search_number++;
        srch_numb = search_number + 1;
        $('#text').selectHighlight(search_number);
        if ( search_count >= 0 ) { 
            scroll_to_word();
            $('#count').html('Показано: <b>'+srch_numb+'</b> из '+$('#text span.highlight').size());
        }
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#F0F0F0" text="black" link="blue" vlink="purple" alink="red">

<div id="search_block" style="display: block; top: 7px; background-color: #f0f0f0;" >
    <input id="prev_search" type="button" value="[" />
    <input id="search_text" type="text" value="поиск" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='поиск';" onfocus="if (this.value=='поиск') 

this.value='';" />
    <input id="next_search" type="button" value="]" />
    <input id="clear_button" type="button" value="X" />
    <br>
    <div id="count" style="font-size:10pt;"></div>
</div>

<div id="container" style="padding: 50px 0 0 0;">
    <div id='content'>
        <div id='text'>
<p>10. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 

ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 

in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 

deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>11. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 

ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 

in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 

deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Благодарю за правку моего вопроса.

Comment: не за что, пожалуйста обратите внимание, что в строенном редакторе есть раздел справки и сниппет для кода http://i.imgur.com/NTaaxk6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачайте код библиотек к себе на сайт.
У вас сайт на https, а вы пытаетесь вставить код с сайта на http.
Браузер блокирует содержимое, загружаемое подобным образом, помечая его как "небезопасное".

Вот цитата из [справки Opera](http://help.opera.com/opera/Windows/2066/ru/private.html#blocked):

> При просмотре страниц через зашифрованное соединение (https://) Opera
>   проверяет, все ли части сайта зашифрованы.Если Opera обнаруживает, что
>   какой-либо активный элемент на странице, например скрипт, плагин или
>   фрейм, обслуживается через открытое соединение (http://), всё
>   небезопасное содержимое блокируется. Это означает, что страница может
>   частично отображаться неправильно.

#### Заблокированные библиотеки в Edge

[image: Заблокированные библиотеки в Edge]

#### Заблокированные библиотеки в Opera

[image: Заблокированные библиотеки в Opera]

#### Заблокированные библиотеки в Firefox Developer Edition

[image: Заблокированные библиотеки в Firefox Developer Edition]

---

#### Пример того, что код рабочий (библиотеки загружены через консоль)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! - заработало.

Comment: И также за пояснения по поводу https

Comment: @HaukwithRGandwiki, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за него и отметьте как верный. Галочка слева от сообщения.

Comment: Отметил, но голосовать пока не имею права.